# Flask Socket on Ubuntu AWS is not receive message/data, but in the local machine it works fine, no Connect refused

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, websocket

Situation:
I deploy my flask server in the AWS EC2 ubuntu and running. And react.js running on my local machine try to test is remote server setup correctly and works, contains Restful API and WebSocket.

Question:
Everything works fine on the local machine which python and react both running on the local machine. When l make flask running on the AWS, the Restful API works fine, but WebSocket is not working, there is no connect refused error, switch protocol is 101 and in the inspector network section is 200 status. Just remote server cannot receiving data. I am not sure what was happended at this time and how to fix that, anyone has the same experience?

this one is my client

```
   const endPoint = "http://3.237.172.105:5000/friends";
   const socket = io.connect(endPoint);
   const addFriends=(friend)=>{
    
        socket.emit("Addedfriend",{username:name , friendName:friendName});

    }
```

this one is my flask start file: call **python3 app.py** to run

```
from logging import debug
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_cors import CORS
from Controller.logReg import logReg
from Controller.profile import profile
from Controller.ticket import ticket
from Controller.personal import personal
import logging
#log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
#log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)


app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")
app.register_blueprint(logReg)
app.register_blueprint(profile)
app.register_blueprint(ticket)
app.register_blueprint(personal)
print("socket started ... ...")


CORS(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("socket opened")
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

this is my socket file: print data is not print anything and I am not sure why

```
@socketio.on('Addedfriend', namespace='/friends')
def add_friend(data, t):
    print("this is from addFriend" + str(data))
    # print("friend SID: "+str(request.sid))
    user = data['username']
    friend = data['friendName']
    user_friends = FriendsDB.find_one({"username": user})['friends']
    if friend in user_friends:
        emit("Addedfriend", {"result": "already added", "friendPhoto":"", "friendStatus": False})
        return
    if FriendsDB.find_one({"username": friend}) is None:
        emit("Addedfriend", {"result": "Not Exist", "friendPhoto": "", "friendStatus": False})
        return
```

[this is the network screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6nZ1.png)

[this is AWS IP address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiCUS.png)

[this is AWS inbound rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuU71.png)